# Wrong inferred lifetime due to associated type

Tags: rust, lifetime

The following code sample is a minified version of a problem I have.

```rust
trait Offset: Default {}

trait Reader {
    type Offset: Offset;
}

impl Offset for usize {}

impl<'a> Reader for &'a [u8] {
    type Offset = usize;
}

// OK
// struct Header<R: Reader>(R, usize);

// Bad
struct Header<R: Reader>(R, R::Offset);

impl <R: Reader<Offset=usize>> Header<R> {
    fn new(r: R) -> Self {
        Header(r, 0)
    }
}

fn test<R: Reader>(_: Header<R>, _: Header<R>) {}

fn main() {
    let buf1 = [0u8];
    let slice1 = &buf1[..];
    let header1 = Header::new(slice1);

    let buf2 = [0u8];
    let slice2 = &buf2[..];
    let header2 = Header::new(slice2);

    test(header1, header2);
}
```

I currently have the code working using `usize` instead of the `Offset` associated type. I'm trying to generalize my code so it can work with other types for offset. However, adding this associated type has caused lots of existing code to stop compiling with errors like this:

```
error[E0597]: `buf2` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:37:1
   |
33 |     let slice2 = &buf2[..];
   |                   ---- borrow occurs here
...
37 | }
   | ^ `buf2` dropped here while still borrowed
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created
```

Reversing the order of `header1` and `buf2` fixes the problem for this example, but I don't want to have to make this change everywhere (and may not be able to), and I don't understand why it is a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Cause

[Variance](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html) is the cause of the problem.

- In `struct Header<R: Reader>(R, usize);`, `Header<R>` is **covariant** w.r.t. `R`.
- However, in `struct Header<R: Reader>(R, R::Offset);`, `Header<R>` is **invariant** w.r.t. `R`.

**Subtyping** is a safe conversion of lifetimes. For example, `&'static [u8]` can be converted to `&'a [u8]`.

**Variance** describes how subtyping is lifted to complex types. For example, if `Header<_>` is covariant and `R` is a subtype of `S`, `Header<R>` is a subtype of `Header<S>`. This is not the case with invariant structs.

In current Rust, **traits are always invariant**, because trait variance can't be inferred nor specified in the current syntax. Same restrictions apply to projected types like `R::Offset`.

In your code, since `Header` is invariant, `Header<&'a [u8]>` can't be upcasted to `Header<&'b [u8]>` even if `'a: 'b`. Since `fn test` requires the same type for both arguments, the compiler required the same lifetime for `slice1` and `slice2`.

### Solution

One possible ad-hoc solution is to generalize the signature for `fn test`, if it is feasible.

```
fn test<R: Reader, S: Reader>(_: Header<R>, _: Header<S>) {}
```

Another solution is to make `Header` covariant somehow.

Maybe it is safe to assume `Header` to be covariant if `type Offset` has `'static` bound, but the current compiler doesn't do such a clever inference.

Perhaps you can split out lifetimes as a parameter for `Header`. This recovers covariance.

```
trait Offset: Default {}

trait Reader {
    type Offset: Offset;
}

impl Offset for usize {}

impl Reader for [u8] {
    type Offset = usize;
}

struct Header<'a, R: Reader + ?Sized + 'a>(&'a R, R::Offset);

impl <'a, R: Reader<Offset=usize> + ?Sized> Header<'a, R> {
    fn new(r: &'a R) -> Self {
        Header(r, 0)
    }
}

fn test<R: Reader + ?Sized>(_: Header<R>, _: Header<R>) {}

fn main() {
    let buf1 = [0u8];
    let slice1 = &buf1[..];
    let header1 = Header::new(slice1);

    let buf2 = [0u8];
    let slice2 = &buf2[..];
    let header2 = Header::new(slice2);

    test(header1, header2);
}
```

Comment: Could we cause unsafe behavior if the function call to `test` were allowed in OP's code? I tried `swap`ing fields ([click](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=791b16918ffb93ccc5b4099f7164d52b&version=stable)) (which is legal in the function, because the two `R`s are the same) to create a dangling reference. But I didn't quite succeed. I wonder if it's possible.

Comment: I ended up solving by changing `Header` to `struct Header<R: Reader<Offset=O>, O: Offset>(R, O);`. Is this semantically equivalent? If so, I would expect the compiler to treat them the same.