# Parameter type with impl may not live long enough with irrelevant parameter

Tags: rust, closures, traits, lifetime

I'm trying to wrap some logic common to many Monte Carlo calculations in a `Mutator`, which contains a set of possible random `Mutation`s that can be applied to a `Configuration` struct. Each `Mutation` generates a `Demutation` operation that reverts it. While the `Mutation` requires a random number generator to operate, the `Demutation` is fully deterministic and does not.

Here's a very minimal definition of the relevant components:

```rs
use rand::Rng;

type MutatorResult<T> = Result<T, ()>;

trait Configuration {}

trait Mutation<C: Configuration> {
    fn execute(&self, configuration: &mut C, rng: &mut impl Rng) -> MutatorResult<Box<dyn Demutation<C>>>;
}

trait Demutation<C: Configuration> {
    fn execute(&self, c: &mut C) -> MutatorResult<()>;
}
```

A simple `Configuration` might look like this, for example:

```rs
struct ConfigurationImpl {
    x: f64,
}

impl ConfigurationImpl {
    fn displace(&mut self, shift: f64) {
        self.x += shift;
    }

    fn random_displace_right(&mut self, rng: &mut impl Rng) -> impl Fn(&mut Self) {
        let shift: f64 = rng.gen();
        self.displace(shift);
        move |c: &mut ConfigurationImpl| c.displace(-shift)
    }
}

impl Configuration for ConfigurationImpl {}
```

Now, when I try to implement a `Mutation`, I run into a problem like this:

```rs
struct MyDemutation {
    undo_closure: Box<dyn Fn(&mut ConfigurationImpl)>
}

impl Demutation<ConfigurationImpl> for MyDemutation {
    fn execute(&self, c: &mut ConfigurationImpl) -> MutatorResult<()> {
        (self.undo_closure)(c);
        Ok(())
    }
}

struct MyMutation {}

impl Mutation<ConfigurationImpl> for MyMutation {
        fn execute(&self, configuration: &mut ConfigurationImpl, rng: &mut impl Rng) -> MutatorResult<Box<dyn Demutation<ConfigurationImpl>>> {
            // This works:
            // let undo_closure = Box::new({
            //     let shift: f64 = rng.gen();
            //     configuration.displace(shift);
            //     move |c: &mut ConfigurationImpl| c.displace(-shift)
            // });
        
            // But this doesn't compile:
            let undo_closure = Box::new(configuration.random_displace_right(rng));
            
            Ok(Box::new(MyDemutation { undo_closure }))
        }
}
```

The result is:

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `impl Rng` may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:94:40
   |
83 | ...guration: &mut ConfigurationImpl, rng: &mut impl Rng) -> MutatorResult<Box<dyn Demutation<ConfigurationImpl>>> {
   |                                                -------- help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `impl Rng + 'static`
...
94 | ...ation { undo_closure }))
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...so that the type `impl Fn(&mut ConfigurationImpl)` will meet its required lifetime bounds

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0310`.
```

How do I tell Rust that the lifetime of the Rng reference is not at all relevant here?

This [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a38828b14f0a1135c2fe98e98c3ee915) contains the code, and a bit more code for the `Mutator` itself, where I was able to rely on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49299043/the-parameter-type-c-may-not-live-long-enough-when-it-doesnt-need-to) to decouple the random number generator from the struct definitions.

Comment: Note: `Fn() -> ()` can be typed as just `Fn()`.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually solved this myself. The key was to add a "leave me alone, none of these should be linked" lifetime signature to the execute function, and work it out from there. Thanks to anyone who may have tried to help!

```rs
trait Mutation<C: Configuration> {
    fn execute<'a,'b,'c>(&'a self, configuration: &'b mut C, rng: &'c mut impl Rng) -> MutatorResult<Box<dyn Demutation<C> + 'static>>;
}
```

Comment: It seems odd that that changes the meaning, because that seems like it ought to be equivalent to the form with elided lifetimes!

Comment: @KevinReid Not exactly - the actual signature should add `'d` with `rng: &'c mut (impl Rng + 'd)`, and if you do it does error.